# Getting CORS error for crunchbase v4 autocompletes API in browser

Tags: javascript, api, browser

I am using `https://api.crunchbase.com/api/v4/autocompletes?collection_ids=organizations&user_key=<MY-PAID-USER_KEY>&query=box` key in browser for typeahead. But I am getting CORS error.

I used the documentation from `https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/Crunchbase/crunchbase-enterprise_api/1.0.3#/Entity/get_entities_organizations__entity_id_`

Earlier I was using `odm-organizations` API mentioned here `https://data.crunchbase.com/v3.1/reference#odm-organizations` which was working fine in the browser, but now it started giving `Usage limit exceeded`

I don't see how to enable CORS for `api.crunchbase.com` in their documentation.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps there is no CORS to enable, perhaps you are expected to make requests from a server, not a browser

Comment: Hey @Gan! did you get to solve this?

Comment: No. I have written a proxy API from server side. And my UI code calls this API which calls crunchbase API.

Comment: Ha, that sucks.. It's autocomplete API.. it's supposed to be called from the frontend directly. Crunchbase API has been a headache for me.